# How to commit changes after SVN import?

Tags: svn

I've created a project, and used `svn import`.  Now I'd like to commit a change to files, how to do that?

I have empty `~/.workspace/project/.svn/entries`.

If I try svn commit I get this:

```
$ svn commit src/dat/Win.java
svn: '/home/st/.workspace/dat/src/dat' is not a working copy
svn: Can't open file '/home/st/.workspace/dat/src/dat/.svn/entries': No such file or
```

directory

… or just `svn commit`:

```
$ svn commit
svn: Can't read file '/home/st/.workspace/dat/.svn/entries': End of file found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before committing, you need to checkout a fresh copy of the just imported files. Delete (or rename) you're project directory, and do `svn checkout [REPOSPATH]`.
Then you have a working copy. After you change a file in you're working copy, you can use `svn commit`.

See [Getting Data into your Repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.tour.importing.html) in the SVN Book.

Answer (score 11):

svn import commit an unversioned file to a repository (on a remote host presumably). After you've done this you need to checkout the repository to you own machine as working copy using

```
svn checkout http://some.repository.net/trunk/ /my/local/path/to/workingcopy
```

which will checkout trunk from the repo to your machine to folder /my/local/path/to/workingcopy. Make changed and then do.

```
svn commit -m "A comment telling what you did the which file"
```

or if you added some files to the working copy do:

```
svn add /path/to/file /path/to/otherfile
```

or

```
svn add /path/to/dir --force
```

which will add everything in the directory and all of it's subdirectories to the working copy, and finally

```
svn commit -m "who did what why"
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot commit changes without checking out a local copy of the repository first.

1. Check out the repository into a local directory using:

   ```
   svn checkout file:///path/to/repo
   ```
2. make changes.
3. Run the following to submit your changes:

   ```
   svn commit
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'svn diff' to see what changes you have outstanding, and commit them with 'svn commit' (to commit all changes), or 'svn commit path/to/file1 path/to/file2' to commit only the changes to those files.

Answer (score 0):

```
svn commit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
svn commit [PATHTOFILE]
```

via svn commit --help