# .svn/entries: No such file or directory

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm using subclipse to commit and update from eclipse. After some trouble today with svn ([Lost .svn/format, what to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026794/lost-svn-format-what-to-do)) I wanted to try and see if I can commit from commandline.

Trying to commit from commandline gives me a

```
.svn/entries: No such file or directory
```

error. I [checked out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817987/how-to-commit-change) my code, and doing
[svn info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943665/how-to-update-a-file-in-svn) gives me

```
Path: .
URL: https://svn.somewhere.ac.uk/svn/some/ndeklein/MS
Repository Root: https://svn.somwhere.ac.uk/svn/some
Repository UUID: *
Revision: 5258
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: anonym
Last Changed Rev: 5258
Last Changed Date: 2012-04-05 13:59:00 +0100 (Thu, 05 Apr 2012)
```

It seems to me that my .svn folder in my root folder misses some necessary files or folders, seeing that it was also missing [format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026794/lost-svn-format-what-to-do). I don't understand how it is possible when getting a fresh check out though, nor how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an SSD disk and Linux? I am, and it's the only time I've seen these kinds of errors (I'm using ext4 and encryption). Try using a hard disk, or else read [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives) very carefully: